Converting Multiple Videos from S3 into GIFs with Random Frames using Python and Lambda
I have a collection of videos stored in an S3 bucket, and I'm looking to automate the process of converting these videos into GIFs using Python and Lambda. Each resulting GIF should be precisely 10 seconds long and should contain random frames sampled from different parts of the corresponding video. By random frames, I mean frames from the beginning, middle, and end of each video, creating a dynamic GIF experience.
I've started implementing this functionality using ffmpeg within a Python Lambda function, but I'm encountering difficulties in achieving the desired outcome.
Could someone provide guidance on how to efficiently accomplish this task? Any insights into Python code for Lambda functions and ffmpeg commands would be greatly appreciated.

The comments are in the code. I imagine that is something like the code below:
import imageio.v3 as iio # pip install imageio | pip install imageio[ffmpeg] | pip install imageio[pyav]
import numpy as np

#######################################################
# The example below only was tested using MP4 videos  #
#######################################################

# make sure it will be the best for your scenario.,.. maybe you will need to improve it!
def get_total_frames(file:str) -> int:
    props = iio.improps(file, plugin="pyav")

    # Make sure the codec knows the number of frames
    assert props.shape[0] != -1

    return props.shape[0]

def extract_Nseconds_into_frames(file:str, n_seconds:int) -> np.ndarray:
    # default is to have 30 frames per second to have a good feel... but change as you wish
    totalframes = get_total_frames(file)
    print(f"Total frames: {totalframes}")

    fps = iio.immeta(file, plugin="pyav")["fps"]
    print(f"Video FPS: {fps}")

    step = int((totalframes/fps) / n_seconds)
    print(f"Step to achieve number of seconds: {step}")

    if step <= 1:
        raise Exception("Your video file dont have frames enough to be extract in desire FPS")

    frames_to_be_extracted = []
    for idx in range(0, totalframes, step):
        frames_to_be_extracted.append(idx)

    print(f"Selected frames (total): {len(frames_to_be_extracted)}")

    img_list = []
    for idx in frames_to_be_extracted:
        img_list.append(iio.imread("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", index=idx))

    print(f"Stacking frames")
    frames = np.stack(img_list, axis=0)

    return frames, fps

def frames_to_gif(gif_path:str, frames:np.ndarray, fps:int):
    print(f"Converting frames into GIF")
    iio.imwrite(gif_path, frames, duration=1/fps/1000)

# "imageio:cockatoo.mp4" is a standard image provided by ImageIO for testing and demonstration purposes
frames, fps = extract_Nseconds_into_frames("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", 3)
frames_to_gif("cockatoo.gif", frames, fps)

